# Cant understand why "recv()" not gets some string from the "sendall()" python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to send chunks of bytes from server to client and then save those chunks in a list.
I do this thing with 20 threads for sending, and 20 threads for recieving.
In each chunk i insert at the start two bytes represents the number of the chunk ID that should be indicator for the client to know in ehach index of the list, the chunk shoukd be placed.

Client:

```
 global chunks
                    chunks = ['' for _ in xrange(WORKERS)]  # That list will hold the chunks before writing it to file.
                    threads_list = []
                    for _ in xrange(0, WORKERS):
                        worker = threading.Thread(target=job, kwargs={"server_tunnel": server_tunnel})
                        worker.start()
                        threads_list.append(worker)

                    for is_end in threads_list:
                        is_end.join()  # Stop the all program till the all file has been sent
```

Client-job function (threading):

```
def job(server_tunnel):
    download = ''

    global chunks
    while not download == "DIE THREAD!":
        curr_bytes = server_tunnel.recv(SPEED)  # 7B 8192 4096
        chunks[int(curr_bytes[0:2])] += curr_bytes[2:]
```

And the server:

```
# Making a list of chunks and send the chunks by workers
chunk = curr_file_size / WORKERS
chunks = []
with open(path, 'rb') as curr_file:
    for _ in xrange(0, WORKERS):
        chunks.append(curr_file.read(chunk))
    chunks[WORKERS - 1] += curr_file.read(curr_file_size % WORKERS)
threads_list = []

for i in xrange(0, WORKERS):
    worker = threading.Thread(target=self.job, kwargs={"curr_file_size": curr_file_size,
                                                       "curr_file": curr_file,
                                                       "client_socket": client_socket,
                                                       "chunk": chunks[i],
                                                       "worker": i})
```

Server-job (threading):

```
def job(self, curr_file_size, curr_file, client_socket, chunk, worker):
    sent = 0
    length_chunk = len(chunk)
    while sent < length_chunk:
        try:
            client_socket.sendall(str(worker).zfill(2) + chunk[sent:sent + SPEED])  # 7a ,8192 4096
            sent += SPEED
        except socket.error:
            print 'One link died. E2'
            self.clients.remove(self.chosen)
            client_socket.close()
            self.chosen = ''
    client_socket.send("DIE THREAD!")
```

Now..
I get this error while trying to send a file from the server to the client:

> chunks[int(curr_bytes[0:2])] += curr_bytes[2:] ValueError: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: '{\xa2'
>
> chunks[int(curr_bytes[0:2])] += curr_bytes[2:] ValueError: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: 'DI' etc..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait a second... these are all on one socket? `sendall` doesn't mean that the message will be in one piece... the sends from 20 threads will be interleaved. `recv` has a similar problem... plus `recv` doesn't necessarily get all the bytes you asked for. If you don't mind external toolsets, consider something that puts a message structure on top of transport streams such as *zeromq*.

Comment: @tdelaney Its not makes things slower then working in sockets?
There is must be a way to make the threads be able to indicate the messege ID even if its cutted messege...

Comment: You can use `threading.Lock` on your `sendall` and `recv` calls to make sure messages don't get chopped up. An update your recv code to read the next block id plus a while loop to get the chunk of data. But its very unlikely you will beet a simple single threaded read/sendall loop.